# what is the name of small win that appear by mouse over & how to create it

Tags: javascript, popup

i want to know the name of small popup window that usually appear by mouse over an object and show some descriptions. for example in the following picture it has appear by mouse over on google search microphone Icon:
[image: i mean the windows that show by red arrow]

and my next question is how to create this popup windows by java script.

Comment: It's called a "tooltip". You can add a `title` attribute to the element and the browser will show one on hover.

Comment: It's "tooltip", provided by `title` attribute of the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In general**

You are looking for the HTML `title` attribute. This attribute is valid on any HTML element, as mentioned here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp

**In HTML**

Thus you can add the `title` attribute to any HTML element. For example:

```html
<a href="#" title="This is your tooltip content">Link</a>
```

I prepared a jsfiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/g2106c9e/

**In Javascript**

You can assign the `title` attribute dynamically to any element.

```js
// Get a DOM element
var element = document.getElementById("some-element-id")

// Set this elements title attribute
element.setAttribute("title", "This is your tooltip content")
```

Here another working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p5sLvd63/